# Select query for loading items on spinner selection

Tags: sqlite, select, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-spinner

i have a spinner filled with value (category from category table) from sqlite now i need a select query to retrieve items into listView. such that on spinner selection change listview values also change . items are coming from another table (items).cid is foreign key in items table and cid is primary key in category table i tried this but showing empty listview....

```
 String select = "SELECT " +
            Support.KEY_INAME + " FROM "
            + Support.TABLE_ITEMS + " LEFT JOIN "
            + Support.TABLE_CAT + " ON "
            + (Support.TABLE_ITEMS + "." + Support.KEY_CID) +" = "
            + (Support.TABLE_CAT + "." + Support.KEY_CID)
            + " WHERE " + Support.TABLE_CAT + "." + Support.KEY_CID + " =?";
```

this is my spinner selection and loading listview data code...

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

             Spinner spinner = (Spinner)parent;

            if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {

                 dbRepo = new DBRepo(getApplicationContext());
                 final List<Support> list = dbRepo.getItems1();
                 adapter = new Custom(Category.this, R.layout.view_entry, list);
                 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Comment: i already mentioned that this is debuged code...after debug showing nothing in listview

Comment: And are you sure the problem is in select not later?

Comment: yes becase when i set last Support.KEY_CID+ "=0" showing items having cid 0

Comment: How are you executing this query? How are you populating the view? There's not enough to go on here.

Comment: now check the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above query is true and alternatively i solve my problem using these two queries

```
  String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM + " WHERE " + KEY_CID + " ='" + cid + "'";
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

OR

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE _CategoryID =? " ,new String[]{cid}, null );
```

and change also change the code spinner.setonItemSelected like this

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                handler = new DBSQLite(getBaseContext());
                String selected = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String cid = handler.getCid(selected);
                final ArrayList<Support> item = handler.getItems(cid);
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(AvailableItems.this, R.layout.available_view, item);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```